# can I filter the list of displayed TFS projects in Team Explorer

Tags: tfs

We are using VS2012 & VS2013 AND TFS 2010? or 2012?

Is it possible to filter the list of displayed projects in Team Explorer?  I only work on a number of projects,  constantly have to scroll and I'm lazy.

***EDIT***
I'm actually interested in filtering the list in **Source Control Explorer** (my misstatement)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only get projects and project collections that you have connected to. If you remove them from appearing in Team Explorer, just click on "Configure Team Projects" link and select only the project that you want to appear. Only that project will appear in Team Explorer.

**EDIT** If you are looking to filter within Source Control Explorer, get the [TFS Source Control Explorer Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dc925252-2e11-46df-9cd0-af4b8097ca4f). It adds a toggle button "Filter folders by folder mapping". When turned on, it will only display folders in Source Control Explorer, which are mapped to your machine. See below

[image]

Comment: You are of course correct.  I mistyped.  I'm looking at the "source Control Explorer". +1 for the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I've modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The default install of that package didn't actually filter properly, but I now at least know where/what to look for. **Correction** Its does work: I had the root of TFS mapped. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Harnid Shahid. He is correct. I dont have the points to comment, but just to note that the filtering is done by a case sensitive workspace path even though TFS' Source Control Explorer's workspaces are not case sensitive.